# How to create swing Tabbed Pane application using the Netbeans GUI editor

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans-8

I am fairly new to Java.  I am trying to create a Java application that has a tabbed pane.

First, I created a Java application named **app1** in Netbeans and then I added a `TabbedPane` to the already existing `JFrame`.

I noticed the code now has a `app1` class extending `javax.swing.JFrame`. It also has a  `private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane2;` at the bottom of the class.

Why aren't there any import statements for `javax.swing.JTabbedPane` and `javax.swing.JFrame` ? A tabbed frame can't be created without at least the `javax.swing.JTabbedPane`.

Also, I noticed the `app1.form` file contains the position and size of the items on the GUI Design area. This could lead to issues if I want to transfer code from one development environment to another.  Is it best to incorporate the form data into the program at the final stage of development?

Thanks.

Comment: Your title does not match with your question, since you apparently managed to create a `JTabbedPane`.

Comment: I haven't created an application that has a tabbed pane yet. When I run the program, the frame is blank.  The GUI editor seems very basic.  Will it show the tabs on the tabbed pane after I add code that creates the tabs?

Comment: Show me what you already have, I cannot guess

Answer (score 3):

This code is not supposed to be read by a human, and imports are unnecessary because the classes are all fully qualified (package name + class name).

I don't know the exact reason for this design choice but I think it enables easier templating : since the code does not depend on any import, you can copy-paste it anywhere, it will work fine without having to care about bringing the necessary imports and merging them to the destination class's imports.

Comment: The form file seems to have some of the object property information.  The source code doesn't show the creation of any object, however, when the application is run an object,(e.g. text box and etc.) is shown on the form.  How does that happen?

Comment: Can you show the code ? Also, I don't know what is this form file you are talking about. If the code is too long, put it on Pastebin and give us the link

Comment: The application name is named app1GUI and not app1. app1 is the project name.  Also, the tabbed pane variable is jTabbedPane1 and not jTabbedPane2 as I previously mentioned.

Comment: I'll have a look at it when I am on my personal machine, if you haven't find yet at that time